# Filtering ids when they have the same value across a column in r

Tags: r, filter

I am trying to filter a dataset when all scores are the same value within each id. Here is my sample dataset looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4,4,5,5,5),
                 score = c(0,1,2,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0,0,0))

> df
   id score
1   1     0
2   1     1
3   1     2
4   1     0
5   1     1
6   2     1
7   2     1
8   2     1
9   2     1
10  3     0
11  3     1
12  3     2
13  3     3
14  3     3
15  4     3
16  4     3
17  4     3
18  4     3
19  4     3
20  5     0
21  5     0
22  5     0
```

In this dataset, I only need to keep `id` `c(2,4,5)` because this `id`s have the same values in the `score` column.

I was only able to filter the `score=0` `id` by

```
df.1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(sum = sum(score)) %>% filter(sum == 0)
```

My desired output would look like:

```
> df
   id score
1   2     1
2   2     1
3   2     1
4   2     1
5   4     3
6   4     3
7   4     3
8   4     3
9   4     3
10  5     0
11  5     0
12  5     0
```

NOTE: the max score is 3 here but I need a global solution if the score is larger than 3.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Use `n_distinct` i.e. `df %>% group_by(id) %>% filter(n_distinct(score) == 1) %>% ungroup`

Comment: @akrun this works great thanks!